# Angualr: how to Pass data with Angular Router

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Good morning,

in a ***app.module.ts***:

```
{path: 'homepage', component: HomepageComponent},
```

in a ***xxx.component.ts*** we have this:

```
private nameFunction(){
    const nameVariable = this.createMyObject(params);
    console.log(nameVariable);
    this.Router.navigate(['homepage']);
}
```

Thanks to the *console.log()* we can see that is an ***Object*** like this:

```
Object: { 
   information1: Object {...},
   information2: Array [...],
   information3: Object{...},
   information4: Array[...]
}
```

my question is:

***how can I pass "nameVariable" inside the new component called "Homepage"***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this:

1- Required path parameters:

```
// Defining route
{path: 'homepage/:object', component: HomepageComponent}
// Navigation
this.router.navigate(['/homepage', {object: JSON.stringify(nameVariable)}]);
// Read
let object = JSON.parse(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get("object");
console.log(object.information1);
```

2- Optional path parameters:

```
// Defining route
{path: 'homepage', component: HomepageComponent}
// Navigation
this.router.navigate(['/homepage', {...nameVariable}]);
// Read
this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get("informationX");
```

3- Query parameters:

```
// Defining route
{path: 'homepage', component: HomepageComponent}
// Navigation
this.router.navigate(['/homepage'], {queryParams: nameVariable});
// Read
this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get("information1");
```

All of three above solutions will spread your object in the URL.

You can also use a shared data member defined in your SharedService which you can populate before performing `this.router.navigate`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you are trying to do, we need more information, but i think it has to be with @Output and eventEmitter.

You can pass data back from the child to the parent component. You have to declare a variable in the child, but with the @Output decorator and a new EventEmitter.

```
@Output() exampleOtp = new EventEmitter<string>();
    
exampleMethodChild() {
     this.exampleOtp.emit(this.example); //your local var
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: My purpose is to be able to see the "nameVariable" object inside the new Component "homepage" so I can modify /update it etc...